# Flex with first child centred and second child at the end

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I push `.right` all the way to the right while keeping `.centred` in the center? (It doesn't need to be with flex, but I would need to keep `.centred` above `.right` on mobile view)

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjZLOv

```
  <div class="flex">
      <div class="centred">
          <div class="a">asdfasdf</div>
          <div class="b">asdfasdf</div>
      </div>
      <div class="right">asdfasfad</div>
  </div>


.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.centred {
    justify-content: center;
}

.right {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `.centred` `inline-block` and use `text-align: center;` on the parent to center it, then float `.right` to the right.

```css
.container  {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.centred {
  display: inline-block;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="centred">
      <div class="a">asdfasdf</div>
      <div class="b">asdfasdf</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">asdfasfad</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution seems to have two problems: 1. the text is not really centered. It's centered in the remaining space. 2. The right aligned item is no longer vertically aligned in its parent. I'm struggling with this myself and so far haven't found anything using only CSS, allowing variable width for right item and no absolute positioning. I'm not sure it's possible. Any ideas?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu ah thanks, 1) I didn't notice it was off center horizontally. 2) I noticed that, too, but that wasn't listed as a requirement. Why not use absolute positioning? I understand it isn't ideal, but OP didn't list it as a requirement, either - seems like an acceptable response. That's what I was going to use but thought this solution would center horizontally.

Comment: I thought `absolute` the first second. But I actually hate it. Conceptually, it's wrong, especially when the right element has more height than the container. It's... dirty? :). I'm not a big fan of what I proposed either, but it's the closest thing to what I'd use in production. That said, I wasted too much time on this already. But I know it will keep eating me and I'll get back on it if I ever find a cleaner solution. Another very simple trick is to set `min-height` to `.right` on `load` and `resize` with `js`. Does the job.

Comment: I happen to work in an environment where I code containers and *content people* fill them up (always in ways I didn't imagine or thought possible, lol). That's why I usually tend to over-think it. Hope I didn't bug you. Cheers!

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu good stuff! Yeah the absolute solution definitely isn't ideal but could work if the center/right content was small and predictable, and OP removes all of that and lets the divs stack vertically in a narrow `@media` query.

Answer (score 2):

You almost have it you just need `margin-left` and direction base:

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.centred {
}

.right {
      margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNqXjo

The code:

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex > * {
    flex: 1;
}

.flex::before {
    content: "";
    flex: 1;
    background: red;
}
```

This makes the items inside the flex container (.flex) use flex.
Then we add another item to use up the rest of the space on the left site so that the rest of the content is pushed to the right.
Configure width with `flex-basis`.

Comment: You're pretty close. But apart from not actually centering/right aligning the contents, your solution is still not complete. When do right elements wrap if they need to? when do center elements wrap when they need to?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu well for that you can set a breakpoint and change flex-direction to column.

Comment: I'm not talking about device width. I'm talking about content width here. What if they're paragraphs?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Well the layout basically makes the content use a certain width and depending on whether that content's display property it will break.